# How to parse nested JSON data structure

Tags: c#, json, json.net, windows-phone-8.1

In a Windows Phone app I need to parse JSON data. I am able to get the values for keys which aren't nested. But if the JSON has arrays inside arrays, then how do I extract values from the JSON file?

In the past what I did was parse the JSON into a JArray object, then from the JToken I got the value of a specified string key.

In the JSON below, `people` has `men` and `women`, and `men` itself has many men with different IDs.  So if I have this complete thing as a JSON string, how do I print the value of the ID of a particular man?  I could have converted into JArray and access indexed values if there were no nested arrays here, but how to do it now?

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "men": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "alex",
                    "age": 25
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "bob",
                    "age": 26
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "charlie",
                    "age": 27
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "women": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "alexys",
                    "age": 25
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "bethany",
                    "age": 26
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "catherine",
                    "age": 27
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft.Json? There doesn't seem to be anything tricky here; without code, it's difficult to tell where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the top-level `JToken`, you can use `SelectToken()` to navigate to the `JArray` that has the data you are interested in:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
JArray men = (JArray)token.SelectToken("people[0].men");
```

From there you can process the `JArray` as you normally would:

```
foreach (JToken m in men)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + m["id"]);
    Console.WriteLine("name: " + m["name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("age: " + m["age"]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Same thing for the women array, except the `SelectToken()` path would be `people[1].women`.

**DEMO:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/7BoiUO

Comment: This was the most helpful parsing technique I got :) Thanks mate

Comment: Same here. You are a savior! So far, this is the only way to "lazily" parse JSONs in C# that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the http://json2csharp.com/
It generates the classes. I can't copy it, because you put here as a picture, not text.
For the array you have to create other class. In your case you will have a People class that contains Men[] and Women[] arrays. The Men and Women classes contain an another array, which contains the Id, Name, Age.
I develop a similar app, and I use the Newtonsoft Json. It works perfectly with the arrays as well.

Comment: Handy little site!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Json.net](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjson.net%2F&ei=A8lsVLPiOIi2uASW0oKYDg&usg=AFQjCNEJdvYd9fvGjDOwwEs-yR8eLL1clA&sig2=I0O8Bjb4tLehM4RbwO8D_Q&bvm=bv.80120444,d.c2E)

You can add it via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).
Here's a good guide to [nested json parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067842/json-net-deserialize-nested-arrays-into-strongly-typed-object)