# How to select an element's value from a JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm having a bit of trouble with C# (VS 2017, .Net 4.6) code. It'd be great if someone could help. I have a JSON file:

```
{
  "makerCommission": 10,
  "takerCommission": 10,
  "buyerCommission": 0,
  "updateTime": 1540015045989,
  "balances": [
    {
      "asset": "BTC",
      "free": "0.22222222",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
      "asset": "LTC",
      "free": "2.00000000",
      "locked": "3.00000000"
    },
    {
      "asset": "ETH",
      "free": "4.00000000",
      "locked": "5.00000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to retrieve the "free" value of any coin using:

```
result = (dynamic)JArray.Parse(MyData)
```

I do not want to retrieve all free values. How can I get 0.22222222, if I pick BTC?

Answer (score 9):

First of all, your overall JSON does not represent an array, it represents an object which *contains* an array.  So you would need to use `JObject.Parse` instead of `JArray.Parse`.

You can use the following [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) code to find a specific `asset` in the array and then get the `free` value from it:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);               // Parse the JSON to a JObject

string free = obj["balances"]                    // Navigate down to the "balances" array
    .Where(jt => (string)jt["asset"] == "BTC")   // Find the object(s) containing the asset you want
    .Select(jt => (string)jt["free"])            // From those get the "free" value
    .FirstOrDefault();                           // Take the first of those
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uFjSib

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You have a JSON object, that contains the array, so you need to parse first the Object and then access the array using the name `balances`.

```
var result = (dynamic)JObject.Parse(MyData);

Console.WriteLine(result.balances); // output JArray ...
```

You can then get the value from the array like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", result.balances[2].asset, result.balances[2].free));
```

The output is the third element from the array:

```
ETH - 4.00000000
```

In order to get only the `BTC` entry you need to filter the array:

```
foreach (var balance in result.balances)
{
    if (balance.asset == "BTC")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(balance.free);
    }
}
```

A better approach would be to create a class that represents the object structure and parse it. The filtering then will be easier using LINQ:

```
public class BalanceItem
{
    public string asset { get; set; }
    public double free { get; set; }
    public double locked { get; set; }
}


public class Items
{
    public List<BalanceItem> balances { get; set; }
}

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Items>(MyData);
var btc = items.balances.FirstOrDefault (b => b.asset == "BTC");
if (btc != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(btc.free);
}
```

The output is: 0.22222222

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `JToken`

The following script gives you the wanted value. Maybe not the conceptually finest approach, but really intuitive.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
          {
              ""makerCommission"": 10,
              ""takerCommission"": 10,
              ""buyerCommission"": 0,
              ""updateTime"": 1540015045989,
              ""balances"": [
                {
                  ""asset"": ""BTC"",
                  ""free"": ""0.22222222"",
                  ""locked"": ""0.00000000""
                },
                {
                  ""asset"": ""LTC"",
                  ""free"": ""2.00000000"",
                  ""locked"": ""3.00000000""
                },
                {
                  ""asset"": ""ETH"",
                  ""free"": ""4.00000000"",
                  ""locked"": ""5.00000000""
                }
              ]
            }";

        var value = "";
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
        var balances = token.SelectToken("balances");
        foreach(var balance in balances){
            if((string)balance.SelectToken("asset") == "BTC"){
                value = (string)balance.SelectToken("free");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992587/how-to-parse-nested-json-data-structure/27029266#27029266)